# How to order by an arbitrary condition in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE Bable
    (
     id int identity primary key, 
     name varchar(20), 
     about varchar(30)
    );
INSERT INTO Bable (name,about) VALUES
('ООО Name Firm 1','texttexttexttext'),
('ООО Name Firm 2','texttexttexttext'),
('ООО Name Firm 3','texttexttexttext'),
('ООО Name Firm 4','texttexttexttext'),
('ООО Name Firm 5','texttexttexttext'),
('ООО Name Firm $1','texttexttexttext'),
('ООО Name Firm $2','texttexttexttext'),
('ООО Name Firm $3','texttexttexttext'),
('ООО Name Firm 6','texttexttexttext'),
('ООО Name Firm 7','texttexttexttext')
```

And I can write a query like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM Bable WHERE about = 'texttexttexttext'
```

How can I alter this query to return results ordered such that those with names containing "$" appear first, followed by those that do not, with each group then ordered by `name` ascending?

**[Structure of the table is here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/14d86)**

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM   Bable
ORDER  BY CASE WHEN name LIKE '%$..' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
          Name
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d1514/1)

Answer (score 2):

You can do the same with `charatindex`

```
SELECT * FROM Bable WHERE about = 'texttexttexttext'
Order by Case When CHARINDEX('$',name)>0 Then 0 Else 1 End,name
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from Bable 
order by charindex('$',name,0) desc, name asc
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d1514/3)