# how make right select? (part2)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

**I have query:**

```
;
WITH ranked AS (
  SELECT
    p.id_price as p_id_price, 
    p.id_service as p_id_service, 
    p.name as p_name, 
    p.name_original as p_name_original, 
    p.id_producer_country as p_id_producer_country, 
    p.id_firm as p_id_firm, 
    f.name as f_name, 
    f.address as f_address, 
    f.phone as f_phone, 
    city.name as city_name, 
    pc.name as pc_name,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY p.id_firm
      ORDER BY
        CASE  -- this criterion puts matching products before non-matching ones
          WHEN p.name like '%test%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1251_CI_AS
          THEN 1 ELSE 2
        END,
        p.id_price  -- you may use any sorting criteria at this point,
                    -- just ensure it makes the results predictable
    ) AS rnk
  FROM Price p 
  left join Firm f 
    on f.id_service=p.id_service 
    AND f.id_city=p.id_city 
    AND f.id_firm=p.id_firm 
  left join City city 
    on city.id_city = p.id_city 
  left join Producer_country pc 
    on pc.id_producer_country = p.id_producer_country 
  WHERE p.id_city='73041' 
    AND p.include='1' 
    AND p.blocked='0' 
    AND f.blocked='0' 
    AND ( f.name like '%test%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1251_CI_AS
       OR p.name like '%test%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1251_CI_AS )
)
SELECT p.name
FROM ranked
WHERE rnk = 1
;
```

in **[this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15563567/how-make-right-select/)** users help and suggested several possible answers.

But in this case we have a very large and complex query.

Tell me please how modification this query that first i get results with firm when have $(on sequence after the $ sign), and then i get results with other firms (order by name asc) ?

Its really or not?

**[Structure tables here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c4802/2)**

**NEED GET RESULT:**
first need get p.name with firms(f.name) when have **$** (in order of priority, ex. Name firm $1, Name firm $2, Name firm $3, ...), and than need get results with other firms (order by p.name)

Comment: what is your desired output based on the sample data on sql fiddle?

Comment: @JW i update my question(see down question please).

Comment: I think it would make sense to write 4-5 example rows to the SQL Fiddle, then the help is much easier, and the desired output is much more understandable

Comment: sorry but tables very big for fiddle. Result example can see here[http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d1514/1]. but in my question me need get p.name(but firms should have order when in fiddle).